# ¿Cómo puedo poner dos ListView compartiendo un único scroll?

Tags: android

Tengo este código en el activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="es.example.red.androidtest.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Y este en el MainActivity.java

```
package es.example.red.androidtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView1;
    private ListView listView2;
    final String[] datos = new String[] {
        "Elemento 1",
        "Elemento 2",
        "Elemento 3",
        "Elemento 4",
        "Elemento 5",
        "Elemento 6",
        "Elemento 7",
        "Elemento 8",
        "Elemento 9",
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);
        listView1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listView2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Cada `ListView` ocupa la mitad de la pantalla y cada uno con su scroll. ¿Cómo puedo poner los dos listviews con un único scroll?

Answer (score 1):

yo uso ese tip, con lo que comenta @elenasys
englobas los dos `ListView` en un control `ScrollView` y después con esa función  `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren` se le asigna la altura total que es necesario para mostrar el contenido entero .

```
 public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

para asignar la altura total del contenido

```
ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lv1);
setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lv2);
```

**Método 2**
Es crear un control propio extendiendo de un `ListView`

Crear el control personalizado `MyListView.java`

```
public class MyListView extends ListView {

    public MyListView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyListView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyListView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightSpec;

        if (getLayoutParams().height == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {

            heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        } else {
            heightSpec = heightMeasureSpec;
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
    }
}
```

Y para poder usar el control que se ha creado `MyListView` dentro del archivo XML

```
 <tu.package.name.MyListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un ScrollView que contenga el layout contenedor de los ListView :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myscrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Recuerda que el ScrollView debe contener solo un elemento, para que pueda realizar sobre el un deslizamiento.

Comment: Hola Elenasys, pero me sigue haciendo scroll por separado :(

Comment: Claro cada ListView tiene su propio Scroll cuando tiene el enfoque, tu quieres que solo se ejecute un scroll o sea que los listView esten fijos?

Comment: Si, que salga en la ventana la primera lista permitiendo hacer scroll y cuando acabe esta salga la otra también haciendo scroll, vamos como si todos los elementos de la lista salgan de golpe y un sólo scroll. Es una pijotada pero que estoy buscando y no veo que se pueda implementar. Si se os ocurre alguna forma o si no, lo dejo así. Un saludo y gracias y aprovecho para agradecerte, Elenasys, toda la ayuda que me están dando con esto de android ;) Un saludo