# ¿Cómo puedo tener scroll en mi ListView con NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, xml

Estoy utilizando `NestedScrollView` y una `ListView` pero esta no se visualiza completa, siempre se recorta ya que no hace *scroll*

¿Qué puedo hacer para tener *scroll* en mi `ListView` utilizando `NestedScrollView`?

`xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="184dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center"
        app:expandedTitleMargin="25dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="105dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/profile_id" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f4f4f4"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/prueba1">

        <View
            android:background="@drawable/degradado"
            android:id="@+id/separador1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listview_tab"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: el NestedScrollView es solo para dar el atributo de scroll al listview no es asi ?

Comment: Para darle Scroll a todo lo que pongas debajo de la ActionBar, pero si lo quitas como me comentan abajo, todo lo que añadas (en mi caso quiero la ListView) se pone encima de la ActionBar (puedes ver la captura que añado) @FelixBeeb

Comment: Y también para que la actionBar suba correctamente, sin NestedScrollView no hace su función correctamente @FelixBeeb

Comment: intenta colocar esto en tu listview app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: @FelixBeeb casi! Ahora si hace el scroll a la perfección incluida la animación de ocultar la barra, pero falta un trozo de listview hacia abajo

Comment: Ah que te refieres que falta un trozo ?

Comment: @FelixBeeb que no se muestra la listview completa al deslizar hacia abajo, faltan algunos Item's

Comment: .NestedScrollView es el problema es que por lo general el listview esta va ffuera del collapsing mira te dejo un donde trataron esto - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558139/collapsingtoolbarlayout-not-workingcollapsingwhen-scrolled

Comment: La solución es añadir  android:layout_height="1555dp" en listview conjunto a la linea que me has comentado, pero creo que tendré problemas en diferentes dispositivos al no utilizar "match_parent" no crees? @FelixBeeb

Comment: Asi es, las densidades de las pantallas arruinan muchas cosas, pero puedes crear diferentes layout para cada pantalla, es como cuando cargas un icono en mimap con diferentes resoluciones

Comment: Pues es lo que haré, diferentes layout ya que no veo otra solución para poder usar match_parent en este layout, gracias! @FelixBeeb

Comment: He actualizado mi pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Nunca ponga un Listview en un ScrollView o NestedScrollView, ya que ya es desplazable.

```
EDITO:

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/activity_cat">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="184dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="105dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                        android:id="@+id/profile_id" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:background="@drawable/ic_mas"
            android:id="@+id/separador1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listview_tab"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:divider="@drawable/ic_realizado"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

saludos

Comment: Como me comentas la ListView se pone encima de la ActionBar @Maguz

Comment: comente tu codigo sin el scrollview, algo anda mal?

Comment: He editado la pregunta para que veas con una imagen el problema que tengo con la solución que me has comentado, la listview se pone encima de la ActionBar @Maguz

Comment: Estoy haciendo pruebas y no se puede quitar NestedScrollView porque entonces no hace la función de ocultar la ActionBar correctamente @Maguz

Comment: tuve que agregar un par de linearlayout para que se respetará la altura. edite mi respuesta

Comment: Nada, al borrar NestedScrollView se pierde la animación de ocultar la actionBar, es decir, tengo que deslizar la actionbar para que se oculte no desde la listview @Maguz

Comment: ouch! tienes un problema. quizas si quitas el modo scroll deNestedScrollView...vuelve a tu codigo original y agregale android:overScrollMode="never" a NestedScrollView

Comment: esta respuesta esta bien, pero si no me equivoco lo que le falta al Listview es  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: @FelixBeeb añadiéndolo tampoco, ya que el scroll de la listview no va conjunto al de la actionbar, por lo tanto se elimina la animacion de la actionbar

Comment: creo que encontré la solución. y no pasa por el layout
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view o http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android/17503823#17503823

Comment: Sigo sin encontrar solución, ni con lo que me has pasado, he actualizado la pregunta @Maguz

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo solvento forzando la asignación de la altura del `ListView` cuando un elemnto con scroll se encuentra dentro de otro, como ejemplo un `nestedScrollView` el height del `listView` solo se asigna a la altura del ítem a mostrar.

Aquí hay una respuesta relacionada
https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/10956/2230

Lo correcto es usar un `recyclerView` con `viewHolders` diferentes para cada tipo de contenido.

- encabezado
- ítem tipo 1
- ítem tipo 1
- ítem tipo 2
- ítem tipo 2
- pie de pagina

Con [FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter) es fácil crear una lista con diferentes elementos.

Comment: Pero mi `listview` la voy rellenando desde `sqlite` por lo tanto va aumentando, no se cortaría por abajo?

Comment: Diría que funciona igual, ya que onMeasure se llama cada vez que la lista cambia de tamaño y allí es donde se calcula lo que debe ocupar toda la listView.

Answer (score 0):

No es un buen patron colocar un listview dentro de un NestedScrollView, pero hay casos como cuando se hace uso del CollapsingToolbarLayout. para este caso una solucio facil es colocar en el NestedScrollView:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

o desde Java

```
mScrollView.setFillViewport(true);
```

como se explica en este articulo: http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/