# List view solo muestra un resultado

Tags: android, android-layout, realm, baseadapter

Estoy creando un `listview` con **Realm** y solo muestra el primer resultado. Con debugger he visto que la variable `position` no aumenta de valor y el recorrida por el `List` es siempre con el mismo valor. En la misma aplicación tengo el mismo código y funciona perfectamente. No se donde puedo estar cometiendo el error:

**El adaptador:**

```
public class AdaptadorFacturas extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Factura> list;
    private int layout;

    public AdaptadorFacturas(Context context, List<Factura> facturas, int layout) {

        this.context = context;
        this.list = facturas;
        this.layout = layout;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return list.size(); }

    @Override
    public Factura getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, null);
        vh = new ViewHolder();
            vh.numfactura = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_numfactura);
            vh.fecha = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_fecha);
            vh.valor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_valor);
            convertView.setTag(vh);
    }
    else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Factura facturas = list.get(position);
        String Vfactura = String.valueOf(facturas.getId());
        Date data = facturas.getDatafactura();
        String Vdata = data.toString();
        vh.numfactura.setText(Vfactura);
        vh.fecha.setText(Vdata);
        vh.valor.setText(String.valueOf(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
            TextView numfactura;
            TextView fecha;
            TextView valor;
        }

  }
```

**Relleno el list con estos datos:**

```
public void listAdapter(int id)
    {
        List<Factura> facturas = realm.where(Factura.class)
                .equalTo("Idcliente", id)
                .findAll();
        adaptadorfacturas = new AdaptadorFacturas(this, facturas, R.layout.adaptador_facturas);
        listfacturas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_facturas);
        listfacturas.setAdapter(adaptadorfacturas);
    }
```

**El layout donde esta el ListView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.ferran.esquemaconservas.Clientes.VerClienteActivity">

    <ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="368dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_cliente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txt_cliente"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editNombreCliente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editCiudadCliente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editDireccionCliente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTelefono"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imgBtnGuardar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cnt_guardar"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imgBtnEliminar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cnt_borrar"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_facturas"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/txt_facturas"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_facturas"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    tools:ignore="NestedScrolling" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: cada ítem del ListView es el layout? lo digo porque tienes un scrollView y el ListView ya tiene ScrollView, en Android no se puede tener dos scrollviews aninados, si quieres mostrar diferente estructura de cada ítem, mejor un recyclerview y con el viewholder cargar un layout o otro. También se puede forzar el scrollview que se extienda a todo lo alto, busca por SOES ambos están respondidos.

Comment: mírate eso https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10671/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-poner-dos-listview-compartiendo-un-%c3%banico-scroll/10677#10677

Comment: Buenas! Pues si el error era el scrollView que tenia puesto en el layout. Muchas gracias a todos!!! Como puedo dar la pregunta por cerrada y daros puntos a todos? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Estoy creando un listview con Realm y solo muestra el primer resultado. Con debugger he visto que la variable position no aumenta de valor y
>   el recorrida por el List es siempre con el mismo valor.

Simplemente revisa si al instanciar tu `Adapter` en verdad tienes valores,
 los valores los envías en un List :

```
 public AdaptadorFacturas(Context context, List<Factura> facturas, int layout) {

        this.context = context;
        this.list = facturas;
        this.layout = layout;
    }
```

ya que **la cantidad de elementos se determina en el método `getCount()`**, en base a los elementos que tengas en tu `List`:

```
  @Override
    public int getCount() { return list.size(); }
```

---

Si lo anterior es correcto entonces tenemos que revisar el layout, como primer consejo cuando tengas un ListView dentro de un ScrollView puedes forzar a que el ListView tome el espacio vacio agregando la propiedad `android:fillViewport="true"`.

Además de estos consejos:

- Usa en este caso un LinearLayout en lugar de ConstraintLayout.
- agrega la propiedad  android:layout_height="match_parent" a los contenedores principales (LinearLayout).

de esta forma tu `ListView` mostraría los elementos correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este sería el layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_cliente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/txt_cliente"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editNombreCliente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editCiudadCliente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editDireccionCliente"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTelefono"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

             <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imgBtnGuardar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cnt_guardar"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imgBtnEliminar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/cnt_borrar"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_facturas"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/txt_facturas"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/list_facturas"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Buenas! Si tengo los valores porque return list.size(); tiene un valor de 3 que son las tres facturas que he hecho de prueva. La verdad es que no entiendo el motivo lo mire por donde lo mire :( Y seguramente deve ser un error muy tonto... Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @Ferran No te preocupes, agrega el layout donde tienes el ListView! :)

Comment: @Ferran ya ví cual es el error!!! te doy consejos para corregir y mostrar correctamente el ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Comprueba en el layout para cada fila en la altura tengas

```
wrap-content
```

y no match-parent esto generaría que cada fila ocupe toda la pantalla.
Como pones que funciona en la aplicación, tal vez sea eso !

Comment: Más bien debe ser que el `height` de los items está a `match-parent`, no el `width`

Comment: Exacto que me confundí con uno y otro. :) ! Edito !

Comment: Buenas! Pues he comprovado lo que comentais y no funciona. Creo que el problema viene por el adaptador porque la consulta con el debug sale correcta pero la variable position siempre tiene valor 0 como si no corriese por las diferentes valores de la consulta.  Alguna idea más? Muchas gracias por la colaboracion pero!

Answer (score 1):

Has listado los items que almacenas en tu List sin el adaptador para ver si contiene lo que esperas ?
Por otra parte, no estoy seguro si puedes almacenar Realm directamente en un List, prueba a usar RealmResults<> en lugar de List<>, y si no quieres cambiar tu adaptador, prueba esta manera:

```
public void listAdapter(int id)
{
    RealmResults<Factura> resultados = realm.where(Factura.class)
            .equalTo("Idcliente", id)
            .findAll();
    List<Factura> facturas = realm.copyFromRealm(resultados);
    adaptadorfacturas = new AdaptadorFacturas(this, facturas, R.layout.adaptador_facturas);
    listfacturas = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_facturas);
    listfacturas.setAdapter(adaptadorfacturas);
}
```

*No he podido probarlo, lo hubiera puesto en comentario pero no puedo por baja reputacion.

Comment: Buenas! Gracias por la ayuda pero sigo sin poder resolver el problema. Viendo lo que comentas el List si que contiene los datos que quiero pero solo aparece el primer registro. Sigo pensando que el problema es de la variable position que siempre esta a 0, en la otra activity donde uso el adapter auemnta en cada item que muestra. Ahora con debuger he visto que marca un error "Cannot find local variable 'position' " puede ser que por eso siempre tenga valor 0 pero no entiendo el porque. Muchas gracias por los aportes! Sigo investigando si se os acude alguna idea sera muy bien recibida! ;)

Comment: @Israel, lo que comentas " no estoy seguro si puedes almacenar Realm directamente en un List, " es algo que tenía duda yo también, pero en realidad si se puede.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que el error sea el `ScrollView` el componente `ListView` ya integra scroll y el layout que cargas a cada ítem, cuelga de un `ScrollView`, solo te muestra un ítem, porque el segundo `ScrollView` no se puede expandir a la altura del `ListView`.

Si necesitas mostrar un elemento con scroll que parte de otro elemento con scroll

[¿Cómo puedo poner dos ListView compartiendo un único scroll?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10671/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-poner-dos-listview-compartiendo-un-%C3%BAnico-scroll/10677#10677)

Answer (score 0):

Tal como lo dijo **Webserveis**, pero podría agregar que al dejar un ListView fuera del ScrollView se corre el riesgo de no ver nada del ListView (el ScrollView no lo tomará en cuenta (a menos que el listView no sea tan extenso y esté arriba del ScrollView) ya que no sería padre de ListView). Lo que yo hice fue dejar el ListView dentro del ScrollView, pero darle un tamaño de altura en concreto, por ejemplo `android:layout_height="400dp"`